# Spring Boot content header for plain text

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, curl, post

I have a spring boot app with an `HTTP` `post` request handler. I want to make it so that when I use the following curl command:

```
curl -d "ncs|56-2629193|1972-03-28|20190218|77067|6208|3209440|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0"
     -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' 'http://localhost:9119/prediction'
```

I don't have to add the header content type.

this is my code:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/prediction", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json"},consumes= "text/plain")
    public ResponseEntity<String> payloader(@RequestBody String params ) throws IOException{
        LinkedHashMap<String,String> x = mockconfig.getHM();
        String[] a = params.split("\\|");
        if(a.length!=18){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Requires 18 parameters");
        }

        if(params.equals((String) x.keySet().toArray()[0])) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(x.get(mockconfig.input1)); 
        }
        else if(params.equals((String) x.keySet().toArray()[1])) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(x.get(mockconfig.input2));
        }
        else if(params.equals((String) x.keySet().toArray()[2])) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(x.get(mockconfig.input3));
        }
        else if(params.equals((String) x.keySet().toArray()[3])) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(x.get(mockconfig.input4));
        }
        else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Inccorect payload");
        }
    }
}
```

I set it so it consumes text/plain but I still need to add the header in the curl command or it throws this error:

```
"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported","path":"/prediction"
```

Any workaround?

I have tried using content negotiator and created this class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
  }
}
```

But this just caused to throw errors in the java console:

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported]
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]
```

and wouldn't return anything in terminal when curling.

Adding this dependency into my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformats-text</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0.pr1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

also didn't get it to work...

EDIT:
I changed my code to what Madhu recommended:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/prediction")
    public ResponseEntity<String> payloader(@RequestBody String params ) throws IOException{
        LinkedHashMap<String,String> x = mockconfig.getHM();
         a = params.split("\\|"); //line 35
        if(a.length!=18){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Requires 18 parameters");
        }

        if(params.equals((String) x.keySet().toArray()[0])) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(x.get(mockconfig.input1)); 
        }
        else if(params.equals((String) x.keySet().toArray()[1])) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(x.get(mockconfig.input2));
        }
        else if(params.equals((String) x.keySet().toArray()[2])) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(x.get(mockconfig.input3));
        }
        else if(params.equals((String) x.keySet().toArray()[3])) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(x.get(mockconfig.input4));
        }
        else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Inccorect payload");
        }
    }
```

and when I do the curl without header it responds with my response entity status

```
"Requires 18 parameters"
```

But when I add the header to the same curl command it spits out the JSON successfully.

The parameters are the same though.

Comment: 'This just throws errors' does not help us to help you. Please add the errors you receive to the body of your question.

Comment: Edited to include errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `consumes= "text/plain"` in your controller method, you would have to pass the content-type header as part of the curl request. Simple way would be to have your controller method as below:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/prediction")
public ResponseEntity<String> payloader(@RequestBody String params ) throws IOException{
   //method implementation
}
```

Then you can use the curl as

```
curl -d "ncs|56-2629193|1972-03-28|20190218|77067|6208|3209440|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0" http://localhost:9119/prediction
```

**UPDATE:**
With reference to this [documentation](https://ec.haxx.se/http-post.html):

> POSTing with curl's -d option will make it include a default header
>   that looks like `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

So when you don't pass the `Content-Type` header in the curl, it would result in sending the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type by curl. Hence it would encode the string, replacing the `|` as below:

```
ncs%7C56-2629193%7C1972-03-28%7C20190218%7C77067%7C6208%7C3209440%7Cself%7C-123%7C-123%7C-123%7C0.0%7C0.0%7C0.0%7C0.0%7C0.0%7C0.0%7C0.0=
```

which would mean that your split regex wouldn't work. So you **MUST** either send `Content-Type: text/plain` in the curl, or just `Content-Type:` which would even work. So the issue that you are facing is with how curl works by default, rather than your java code.

Comment: Hey, so this kind of work but it broke the logic of my method...it returns the error message in my response entity that it requires 18 parameters when there is in fact 18 parameters in the input. But when I declare the content header in curl again it returns the JSON validating the 18 parameters. I have edited my question for further clarification.

Comment: @schooner_101 I've updated my answer which would explain you the issue that you're facing. Let me know if it clears your doubt or not.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way I can get around this?

Comment: @schooner_101 if your requirement is not to pass the content-type in the curl at all, then you know that curl will add the default header and that'll encode the data, resulting in the `|` regex not working in your code. It can be solved by changing your regex to split based on `%7C`, but I'm not sure if you want to take that path. But otherwise, there isn't any other way around this to opt out of sending the content-type header in the curl. The issue you're facing for your requirement is due to how curl works, rather than your java code.